# position fixes bottom not working on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, css-position

Very unfortunately the `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` only on iOS Safari.

There are some online solution which says use `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` that also doesn't work for this bug.

iOS version is **11.4**

Demo: https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/BqBezY

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow, green);
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">Hello</a>
```